# PyMongo adding emails?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I am currently working on a Flask and Heroku application and I use a MongoDB to save user signup information. The problem I am having is that when I try to save an email it gives me the error:

```
InvalidDocument: key 'email@domain.com' must not contain '.'
```

I would also like to know how to ensure that each email is unique and is not previously in the database, without having to query the db.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import os
import re
from pymongo import MongoClient
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, redirect
import jinja2

email_regex = re.compile(r"^[\S]+@[\S]+\.[\S]+$")
password_regex = re.compile(r'^[a-zA-Z]\w{3,14}$')

client = MongoClient("mongodb://<user>:<password>@linus.mongohq.com:11077/users")
db = client.get_default_database()
users = db.users


app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/signup', methods=['GET','POST'])
def signup():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form.get('email')
        name = request.form.get('name')
        password = request.form.get('password')
        v_password = request.form.get('v_password')
        if email == '' or name == '' or password=='' or v_password =='':
            return render_template('signup.html', b_error="Cannot leave any field blank")
        elif not(email_regex.match(email)):
            return render_template('signup.html', e_error="Please enter valid email!")
        elif not(password_regex.match(password)):
            return render_template('signup.html', p_error="Please enter valid password")
        elif password != v_password:
            return render_template('signup.html', m_error="Passwords do not match")
        else:
            users.insert({name:name, email:email,password:password})
            return redirect('/')
    return render_template('signup.html')
```

Is there anyway that I can set up a model for the db to follow so that I can set the emails to be unique, make the fields not required/required, and allow me to save emails?

Comment: You should use proper keys for your documents. `'name'` instead of name, `'password'` instead of `password`. It will be very hard to use your documents when you retrieve them if they all have different keys. How would you distinguish between a user's name and password when displaying information about them?

Comment: I had no idea that I needed to keep make the key a string, that explains the key error. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to ensure that a value in a collection is unique is to use a unique index.

In the MongoDB shell it would be:

```
db.users.ensureIndex({email: 1, unique: true})
```

Using PyMongo it's something like:

```
users.ensure_index([('email', 1)], unique=True)
```

The `1` in these examples orders values in the index in ascending order. This should be sufficient for your use. PyMongo offers `pymongo.ASCENDING` and `pymongo.DESCENDING` as conveniences.

More details are available [in the docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/).

Comment: I added this line: 
users.ensure_index({'email': 1}, unique=True)  
directly after users = db.users  
but I get this error  

 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 42, in _index_list
    raise TypeError("if no direction is specified, "
TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list

Comment: Thinking about it, the syntax in Python is a little different. I'll edit the post.